# How to maintain session in java

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I know following are the ways to maintain or session tracking in java but looking for a good one

- URL rewritting
- Hidden form fields
- cookies
- Session object like setAttribitute() and session.getAttribute()

If the client browser has blocked accepting and storing cookies then last 2 ways are not valid.In hidden form fields I need to pass the hidden values in each and every page inside form.So suppose If I am just using `response.sendRedirect()` Then hidden form field is of not use.The remaining is URL rewriting in which I will pass JsessionID in the URl.So My question by knowing the sessionID isnt the unauthorized persons can able to access the pages.
For example There are 3 pages login,register,send.So after login user can register and/or send.So if any one knows the sessionID cant he/she go direct to register/send page.If yes Please tell me how to prohibit this

Comment: What web server are you using.  Shouldn't this work out of the box on Tomcat? The servlet container should set a request parameter JSESSIONID on the first use of the session, and if the client doesn't send back a response signalling that it accepts cookies, the container is supposed to contiue to use this parameter ... I think.

Comment: @user2310289 I use tomcat webserver,even i know the sessionID then isnt it possible to directly go the page which ever I want.Why to login

Comment: I guess this is true if the session has not expired

Comment: Session tracking & authentication are two diff things don't club them.

Answer (score 2):

As of Servlet 3.0 (Apache Tomcat 7 onwards) if you use SSL then you can configure your application to track sessions based on the SSL session ID. The downside is that everything has to be over SSL. The advantages are that the session is strongly tied to the SSL connection. Only the user that created the connection to the server that has the correct SSL session has access to the session. Even if an attacker knows the session ID, they can't access the session.

One word of caution, this form of session tracking is the least widely used so it may not have been as heavily tested as the more usual cookie and URL re-writing mechanisms.

Comment: i dont want to use cookies,so you would suggest to go for url rewritting

Comment: No. I'm suggesting you use SSL and use the SSL session tracking mechanism introduced in Servlet 3.0.

Comment: you said **this form of session tracking is the least widely used** I didnt understand properly.Out of the four which one should I use?

Comment: That is up to you to choose based on your requirements and the pros and cons of each option. Based on your question, my recommendation is to use the SSL session ID tracking mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/cprs_best_practice.html) which outlines `Best practices for using HTTP sessions`

Including

- javax.servlet.http.HttpSession.invalidate()
- Use HTTPS

Comment: for HTTPs I need to buy ssl certificates which are costly and As far as I know used just to pass password which is highly secured.Isnt it?

Comment: For Https you could use self-signed certs, but if you and your customers are serious about security then buying a cert is not so expensive.

Comment: please see this,these are highly expensive http://www.symantec.com/page.jsp?id=compare-ssl-certificates

Answer (score 0):

With standard solutions you can't.

You can add some measure of security by adding request originator IP address verification, but that's also fooled easily. (to clarify *some* here means very tiny itsy bitsy little bit of)

So the secure route is to not use URL Rewriting to maintain session in secure application.

However you may be able to get some security by keeping the JSessionID as a separate encrypted attribute that which will be decrypted by a middle-ware or a load balancing server sitting between the client and your application servers. This of course is just a thought, I haven't, fortunately ever had to try something like that out :-)

Comment: I think that jsessionID is stored in the browser itself.So how to encrypt or decrypt

Comment: It's not in the browser, it's in the URL incoming and outgoing to and from your server...

Comment: I mean to say as the cookies are stored in the memory similarily arent the jessionID stored in the memory

Comment: Dude I thought you are asking about securing URL Rewriting... Are you aksing about cookies as well?

Comment: No no i dont want cookies.My aim is just to prohitbit hackers from accessing

Answer (score 0):

Session tracking & authentication are two diff things don't club them.

Understanding your requirement I see you want to secure the sessionid of the user.

1. Evasdroping: If someone is listing to the request & response in the middle he can take the sessionid and use it. The best way would be to use a SSL. This ensures no one is listening in the middle.
2. Sessionid stolen from Client side: Normally this should be taken care by the browser and OS. So your user is as secure as the system he has.

Comment: Whichever you use, you have to send session id from client to server at each request. Its best to let server take care of it.